# Heading elements font size changed after restart

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm designing a web page using Angular and when I served the project this morning (from where I left off yesterday), all the heading elements became a lot smaller. Here's a side by side comparison

[Left is with clean angular project, right is my current one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxpJn.png)

Stuff I tried

1. Clearing out my styles.css file (empty) which didn't help
2. Clearing out my index.html (default state), did nothing either
3. On-page .css is empty as well
4. Removing extra styles from angular.json (leaving only src/styles.css), still nothing

I'm quite new to HTML/Angular so at this point I'm out of ideas on where to look

Comment: Check in F12 (dev tool) what css override the header style

Comment: Hi I'm not too sure what to look for. Here's my styles.css, the page with headers and F12 expanded in 1 image https://prnt.sc/126phlr. I've tried removing the roboto font and it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are loading the font correctly. The picture shows that you have commented out the google fonts code.

Comment: Commented it on purpose to ensure it wasn't interfering with the rest of the page (since they aren't there by default). Either way I tried the code with and without the font and it has no difference (still not the default angular look)